# Git command to display HEAD commit id?

Tags: git, version-control

What command can I use to print out the commit id of HEAD?

This is what I'm doing by hand:

```
$ cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/v3.3
$ cat .git/refs/heads/v3.3
6050732e725c68b83c35c873ff8808dff1c406e1
```

But I need a script that can reliably pipe the output of some command to a text file such that the text file contains exactly the commit id of HEAD (nothing more or less, and not just a ref).  Can anyone help?

Comment: I have a similar question before. And it was well answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44994626/why-git-use-2-different-commands-to-show-head

Answer (score 654, accepted):

Use the command:

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

For the short version:

```
git rev-parse --short HEAD
```

Comment: For anyone looking for the short version of the hash, `git rev-parse --short HEAD` will work.

Answer (score 72):

```
git log -1
```

for only commit id

```
git log | head -n 1
```

Comment: Thanks, it's easy

Comment: Just FYI: `git log | head -1` is as same as `git log | head -n 1` .

Comment: Although the OP has only asked for the commit ID of HEAD, `git log -1` is very useful. Because it also displays the commit message and other details which makes further analysis/comparison easy. Thank you!

Answer (score 21):

Old thread, still for future reference...:) even following works

```
git show-ref --head
```

by default HEAD is filtered out.
Be careful about following though ; plural "heads" with a 's' at the end. The following command shows branches under "refs/heads"

```
 git show-ref --heads
```

Comment: using these commands in a (large) git repo, I get two lines from `git show-ref --heads` and 6290 lines from `git show-ref --head`. so if you want just a single hash, this gives maybe not the intended result.

Answer (score 16):

You can specify `git log` options to show only the last commit, `-1`, and a format that includes only the commit ID, like this:

`git log -1 --format=%H`

If you prefer the shortened commit ID:

`git log -1 --format=%h`

Answer (score 6):

Play with Bash:

```
git show HEAD | sed -n 1p | cut -d " " -f 2
```

Answer (score 1):

`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`

Comment: This does not show commit ID, but rather any names (like branches or tags) associated with the commit. This is not what the original user wanted.

Comment: @AsfandQazi but it was exactly what I wanted to know, and my google search gave me this article at the top.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command

`$ git rev-list HEAD`

You can also use the `head` Unix command to show the latest `n` `HEAD` commits like

`$ git rev-list HEAD | head -n 2`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
git log -g branchname
```

to see `git reflog` information formatted like the `git log` output along with commit id.