# Why does git uses 2 different commands to show HEAD?

Tags: git

I noticed there are 2 HEADs:

- .git\HEAD
- .git\refs\remotes\origin\HEAD

When I use `git show-ref HEAD`, it only gives me this:

```
ce0762c073b407d794f54f0b5d2a50375fdcb609 refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
```

Whle when I use `git rev-parse HEAD`, it gives me the value of .git\HEAD:

```
a758e523fe40e799194878bac567b7f4b8eec2b9
```

Why Git use 2 different commands to show HEAD? Any strong reason?

Comment: Do you mean `git rev-parse HEAD`?

Comment: @Schwern Thanks for the comment. Yes, I mis-type it. Corrected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`git-show-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-ref) shows a list of references in your repository and their commit IDs. It should probably be called `git-show-refs`. It's preferred over directly referencing files in the `.git` directory.

When you say `git show-ref HEAD` you're not asking for `HEAD`. What you're asking for is any references in the list which match the pattern `HEAD`. `HEAD` itself is normally filtered out, so you get `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`. You can include `HEAD` with `--head`.

```
$ git show-ref --head HEAD
f37beeea95f3b0e6b064f6d4b5f835a058e0568c HEAD
aa1124b89f38eed793e2b9f2d2b2ba5d80a27a20 refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
```

So you shouldn't be using `git show-ref <ref>` to look up references.

---

[`git-rev-parse`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse/) takes a revision parameter and gives back a commit ID. Its meant to deal with the myriad different ways you can refer to a commit. For example...

```
$ git rev-parse --verify master
aa1124b89f38eed793e2b9f2d2b2ba5d80a27a20
$ git rev-parse --verify heads/master
aa1124b89f38eed793e2b9f2d2b2ba5d80a27a20
$ git rev-parse --verify refs/heads/master
aa1124b89f38eed793e2b9f2d2b2ba5d80a27a20
```

`git rev-parse --verify <ref>` is what you should be using to look up the commit ID of a reference.

Answer (score 3):

`.git/HEAD` is used by Git to hold the current ref. So when you're on `master`, it will be `ref: refs/heads/master`. When you are on `detached HEAD`, it will be a commit's hash.

`.git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` is actually a remote ref that points to the default branch on remote. When master is the default remote branch, it will be `ref: refs/remotes/origin/master` (if your remote is origin). It's possible to have a default remote branch other than `master` but I have noticed that it will not correctly reflect that.

But

```
$ git remote show github
```

will always tell you the correct default remote branch.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8841024/58678) of [How does origin/HEAD get set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839958/how-does-origin-head-get-set) for more details.

`git show-ref` shows you refs, which are local branches, remote branches, tags, stash refs.

With

```
git show-ref HEAD
```

Git is using the "HEAD" as pattern

```
git show-ref [-q|--quiet] [--verify] [--head] [-d|--dereference]
         [-s|--hash[=<n>]] [--abbrev[=<n>]] [--tags]
         [--heads] [--] [<pattern>…​]
```

and only showing refs that match.

See [git-show-ref doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-ref).

I mostly use `git branch` with `-a` or `-r` options to see branches, `git tag` to see tags, and rarely use `git show-ref`.